# How to know how much time cost by "synchronized" code, in Java?

Tags: java, monitor, synchronized

I've a Java application, which is not fast enough as I expected. I've done a lot of searches of how to improve it, but not lucky.

Now I'm reviewing the code, and found there are a lot of `synchronized` keyword in the code. I'm thinking if they took too much time on waiting the locks.

Is there any tool to check how much time they cost? Thus I can find a better solution if they do cost too much time.

Comment: If `synchronization` is done at bigger blocks than necessary they can lead to reduced performance due to unnecessary waiting.

Comment: Have you tried any profiling tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was going to suggest the Thread Monitor feature of [jvisualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) and, while looking for a screen shot, ran into this blogpost: [Detecting Thread Contentions](https://www.nuxeo.com/blog/detecting-threads-contention/). It's way better than just a screenshot :).

But here it is anyway:
[image: thread contention in jvisualvm]
(image credit: aforementioned blog post)

Answer (score 1):

A good profiler will be able to pinpoint the methods that are causing slowness it may not be related to the synchronization at all. Also looking at the state of the threads in profiler may reveal if there is too much of waiting going on because of the synchronization. In any case unless the synchronized keyword is being used without reason it may be counter productive to remove it for the sake of performance.

Comment: If `sunchronization` is not needed it will lead to performance loss.If `synchronization` is needed i)it should be done to the proper levels of granularity ii)if it is removed it will not be counterproductive-it will be a mess

Comment: user384706 I agree. OP needs to understand why the code is synchronized only then suitable remedy can be taken.

Answer (score 1):

The cost of synchronization is usually small.  The problem is usually what you do in the synchronization blocks. Make sure you don't do any IO, (socket or network) and ideally no system calls at all and the lock time will be sub-microsecond for simple tasks.